# Gravitational Null Points in a system of point masses

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, equilibrium

For an equilateral triangle formed by 3 point masses which has a circumradius 'a' there are 4 null points: The centroid and 3 other points on the angular bisectors of the three sides.

[image]

On calculation we can find out that they are at 0.285a distance from the centroid/circumcenter.

Now if we calculate the number of gravitational null points for a square made of 4 point masses and a regular pentagon made of 5 point masses we get that the distance of the null points from the centre is 0.55a and 0.69a for a square and pentagon respectively. There are 5 null points for a square and 6 null points for a pentagon. (including the central null point)

[image]

[image]

On observation we notice that for an n sided polygon formed by n equal point masses, there will be 'n+1' gravitational null points. So for a hexagon there will be 7, an octagon 9 &c. &c.

We also notice that the null points seem to be getting farther and farther away from the central null point i.e. the center of the regular polygon.

As n tends to infinity there then should be infinite null points all spaced at an infinitesimal separation from the sides of the regular polygon.

So what I did was I tried to get the null points for an infinite sided polygon i.e. approximately a ring. I took a random point that is 'r' distance away from a ring of mass 'M' and radius 'R' with a uniform mass density.

[image]

Now to get this value of this integral I plotted this integral on desmos and I checked for the number of points where the integral vanishes

[image]

As we can see the gravitational field is only zero at a = 0 (r/R = 0) i.e. at the center of the ring.

(Note that we should only be worried about the values of a till 1, because if a > 1 this means that r>R, which is outside the discussion.)

Now here is where my doubt arises, why does the number of null points tend to infinity (The limit of (n+1) as n tends to infinity is infinity) but become only 1 for an infinite sided polygon i.e. approximately a ring.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the position vector to the mass

$$\mathbf P= \left[ \begin {array}{c} R\cos \left( \alpha \right) -r
\\  R\sin \left( \alpha \right) \end {array} \right] 
$$

with $~G\,M~=1$ you obtain

$$\mathbf g=\frac{1}{\mathbf P\cdot\mathbf P}\,\hat{\mathbf{P}}= \left[ \begin {array}{c} {\frac {R\cos \left( \alpha \right) -r}{
 \left(  \left( R\cos \left( \alpha \right) -r \right) ^{2}+{R}^{2}
 \left( \sin \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) ^{3/2}}}
\\  {\frac {R\sin \left( \alpha \right) }{ \left( 
 \left( R\cos \left( \alpha \right) -r \right) ^{2}+{R}^{2} \left( 
\sin \left( \alpha \right)  \right) ^{2} \right) ^{3/2}}}\end {array}
 \right]=
 \left[ \begin {array}{c} {\frac {R\cos \left( \alpha \right) -r}{
 \left( {R}^{2}-2\,R\cos \left( \alpha \right) r+{r}^{2} \right) ^{3/2
}}}\\ {\frac {R\sin \left( \alpha \right) }{ \left( 
{R}^{2}-2\,R\cos \left( \alpha \right) r+{r}^{2} \right) ^{3/2}}}
\end {array} \right]
$$

the integral $~ g_x~$ is
$$\int g_x\,d\alpha=\rm Elliptic(R,r,\alpha)$$

from here I plotted the result for $~ R=1~,r=0.7~$ and  $~R=1~,r=0.3~$ over $~\alpha=0..2\pi$.

[image]

you can see that the zeroing is independent of the geometry parameter $~R~,r~$

---

I don't think that your results are correct ?

to obtain the gravitational null point I use this equation

$$\mathbf F=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\mathbf p_i-\mathbf s}{|\mathbf p_i-\mathbf s|^3}=0$$

where $~n~$ are the number of the points on the circle (radius a). $~\mathbf p_i~$ are the $~x~,y~$ coordinates of the points and $~\mathbf s=[s_x~,s_y]^T~$ the solution that we are looking for.

because the symmetrie $~s_y=0~$ from here
$$F_x(s_y=0)=F_x(s_x)=0\tag 1$$

the solution $~s_x~$ of equation (1) must be real and $-a\le s_x\le a$

**Results**

$$n~=3~,\phi_0=\frac{\pi}{3}$$
$$s_x=0.2847 a$$

$$n~=4~,\phi_0=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

$$s_x=\pm 0.5469 a$$

$$n~=6~,\phi_0=\frac{\pi}{6}$$

$$s_x=\pm 0.77278 a$$

$$n~=12~,\phi_0=\frac{\pi}{12}$$

$$s_x=\pm 0.9330 a$$

obviously if $~n\mapsto \infty ~$ the solution $~s_x=\pm a~$

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm confused as to what "Elliptic(R,r,)" is and I don't understand how you got the field to be zero inside the ring (r = 0.7, r = 0.3), which is not possible due to the lack of 3d-symmetry in the field. I'm still in high school, so could you please explain those terms.

Comment: @SavithRāllapallí I just used your equation to evaluate the integral : Please see neu edit